# Set new string through reflect.Value.SetString

Tags: go

Having following piece of code:

```
func MakeMap(fpt interface{}) {
   fnV := reflect.ValueOf(fpt).Elem()
   fnI := reflect.MakeFunc(fnV.Type(), implMap)
   fnV.Set(fnI)
}

func implMap(in []reflect.Value) (retSlc []reflect.Value) {
   fun := in[0] // Function to be applied to each of string elems
   str := in[1] // Passed string

   // Prepare for creating new result string as strings in go are immutable.
   var builder strings.Builder
   builder.Grow(str.Len())

   // Convert string to slice of runes for utf-8 compatibility.
   extractedString := []rune(str.String())
   // Iterate over all runes in string and apply passed function to each.
   for i := 0; i < len(extractedString); i++ {
       // reflect.Value.Call expects slice of reflect.Values so we pack it
       // into one.
       replaceWrapper := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(extractedString[i])}
       // As return value is also slice of reflect.Value's, we extract
       // only expected element by [0]
       replaceVal := fun.Call(replaceWrapper)[0]
       builder.WriteRune(replaceVal.Interface().(rune))
   }
   // ##################
   // PANIC - panic: reflect: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using unaddressable value
   str.SetString(builder.String())
   // Tried:
   // - creating temporary value,
   // - retStr := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(builder.String())), but still cannot use Set()
   // ##################

   retSlc = []reflect.Value{str}
   return
}

func main() {
   var fun func(func(s rune) rune, string) string
   MakeMap(&fun)
   str := "data_人生ってなに_пустота"

   fun(func(s rune) rune {
    return s + 1
   }, str)

   fmt.Println(str)
}
```

I have encountered a completely new beast which despite my efforts to understand laws of
assignability in golang is still mysterious after habits from C/C++.

From golang docs: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.SetString we can see that it panics `if CanSet() is false.`
Where in CanSet() `A Value can be changed only if it is addressable and was not obtained by the use of unexported struct fields`.

[This great article](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoAddressableValues) explained me a lot about addressability in go, although I'm still not sure how panic in above example could be elegantly solved and how stack and heap works in Go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the generated function is intended to return the modified string.  Given that, the end of the `main` function should look something like this:

```
str2 := fun(func(s rune) rune {
 return s + 1
}, str)

fmt.Println(str2)
```

Return a new sting value instead of modifying the generated function argument. The function arguments are not settable.

```
func implMap(in []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
    fun := in[0] // Function to be applied to each of string elems
    str := in[1] // Passed string
    var builder strings.Builder
    builder.Grow(str.Len())
    extractedString := []rune(str.String())
    for i := 0; i < len(extractedString); i++ {
        replaceWrapper := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(extractedString[i])}
        replaceVal := fun.Call(replaceWrapper)[0]
        builder.WriteRune(replaceVal.Interface().(rune))
    }

    // Previous lines are same as before (without comments).
    // Return result with reflect.Value from builder's string.
    retStr := reflect.ValueOf(builder.String())
    return []reflect.Value{retStr}
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HAe7d4G2meN).

Reflection is not needed in the MakeMap implementation. Here's a rewrite with reflection removed:

```
func MakeMap(fn *func(func(s rune) rune, string) string) {
    *fn = func(mapping func(rune) rune, s string) string {
        var builder strings.Builder
        builder.Grow(len(s))
        extractedString := []rune(s)
        for i := 0; i < len(extractedString); i++ {
            builder.WriteRune(mapping(extractedString[i]))
        }
        return builder.String()
    }
}
```

Use the [strings.Map](https://godoc.org/strings#Map) function to do the core of the work:

```
func MakeMap(fn *func(func(s rune) rune, string) string) {
    *fn = func(mapping func(rune) rune, s string) string {
        return strings.Map(mapping, s)
    }
}
```

Simplify all of this by using strings.Map directly:

```
str := "data_人生ってなに_пустота"
str2 := strings.Map(func(s rune) rune { return s + 1 }, str)
fmt.Println(str2)
```